# How to get current user details in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Sorry that i couldn't post image as my reputation is under 10 and I'm new to here.I have a question on this, i have 2 column which are "created_by" and "modified_by" , i want to pass the user id into the database at back-end, but it shows me error on this and i have no idea how to do it anymore . Can someone help me out

```
    $policy = new Policy([
        'id' => $request->get('id'),
        'policy_category_id' => $request->get('policy_category_id'),
        'policy_title' => $request->get('policy_title'),
        'version_no' => $request->get('version_no'),
        'policy_details' => $request->get('policy_details'),
        'expiry_date' => $request->get('expiry_date'),
        'file_path' => $request->get('file_path'),
        'created_by'=> auth()->user(),
        'modified_by'=>auth()->user()
    ]);



    try {
        $policy->save();
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
        if ($errorCode == '1062') {
            $status1 = 'failed';
            $statusMsg1 = 'Failed to Create, Duplication Code ' . $request->get('code') . '!';
            return redirect()->back()->with($status1, $statusMsg1);
        }

    }
```

> Error ( Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_by' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `company_policy` (`id`, `policy_category_id`, `policy_title`, `version_no`, `policy_details`, `expiry_date`, `file_path`, `created_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (333, 333, 333, 333, 333, 3333-03-31, 33, {"id":1,"name":"John Smith","email":"john_smith@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2019-10-21 01:54:14","updated_at":"2019-10-21 01:54:14"}, 2020-01-20 01:26:41, 2020-01-20 01:26:41))
>   http://localhost:8089/policy )

Comment: are you sure there is created_by field in your policy table ?

Comment: yes, i'm sure @Qonvex620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you get the details of the authenticated user

get all details of the current user

```
Auth::user() // returns an instance of the authenticated user...
```

get the id of the current user

```
Auth::id()  // returns the id of the authenticated user...
```

get the properties of the current user

```
Auth::user()->firstname
Auth::user()->lastname
```

Comment: my login user is with email and password

Comment: that's only an example, but you can select only what details you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
   1) use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

      Auth::user()->id;

   2) auth()->user()->id;
```